# Google spreadsheet crossing data with Filter not working

Tags: filter, spreadsheet

Morning all,

First time using stackoverflow, I´m a regular Spreadsheet user but I´ve come across a problem I just can't wrap my head around. I have the following set of data on one sheet (arbol):

```html
Feña C   |      Feña C            Rod     Bryan   Ale
Bryan    |      Bryan             Rod     Feña C  Ale
Rod  |      Rod
---------------------------------------------------------       
Evaluador|  Autoevaluación    Jefe    Par1    Par2
```

that I need to rearrange as follows on another sheet (ArbolCruzado).

```html
   -     |  Feña C          Bryan           Rod         Ale
------------------------------------------------------------------    
Feña C| Autoevaluacion  Par1            Jefe            Par2
Bryan | Par1            Autoevaluacion  Jefe            Par2
Rod   |                             Autoevaluacion
```

I´d usually try a filter within a filter but so far I keep getting mismatched errors. My approach on the second sheet was to use:

```html
=(Filter(Filter(Arbol!>B1:999,Arbol!A:A="Evaluador"),(Arbol!A:A)="A2", (Arbol!B1:999)="B1"))
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.